# Update Table created from a query with same query

Tags: ms-access, powerbi

I have a power BI report, which gets it's data from table in a MC Access database.

I have to update these tables in Access often, to get up to date data in my report. But I can't figure out how MS Access query, can update all rows with the same query it was made from. That includes removing rows from the old table, if they do not exist in the new query.

I can delete the table and then use the query again. But power BI loses it's reference, and I have to create the graphs again. I'd like to keep the Access table, but get the content replaced the content of the next query run.

Comment: What happens when you use the Refresh button in Power BI? Does that not pull in the updated data?

Comment: @AlexisOlson It gets an error, because I deleted and created new tables from the Access.

Comment: Can you make your query into a view so that Power BI will pull whatever the most current data is?

Comment: have you tried using SQL `DELETE` and then SQL `INSERT` on the existing table?